# app not compatible - but only on Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android < 4.x

Tags: android, compatibility

I have a really weird issue with app compatiblity since Google Play.

There are several users who have a Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android version < 4.x and they cannot see my app in Google Play anymore.

With Google market it worked fine as well as with Android 4.x and Google Play.

Even in Google's compatibility list of this published app it says that these Samsung Galaxy i9100 are compatible. But still certain users cannot find the app on their Galaxy I9100 phones.

Searching the app on a PC shows up, but is says it is not compatible with Samsung Galaxy S2 phone.

In my manifest I have:

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="7" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
```

The app also uses the standard licencing method.

There seeem to be more - some very popular apps - that have the same problem.

**Anyone found a solution FOR DEVELOPERS, ie what do I have to do with my app so it becomes visible and compatible?**

I also tried to SDK 9 and above, but did not help.

(as opposed to solutions that require anything to be done to the phones)

Comment: That's weird... do you know what those phones are reporting as their API via code ( vs. the stated specs )

Comment: Can you run "aapt dump badging" on your APK and post the output?